# Tapping camera save button action opening again camera in android jellybean

Tags: android, android-camera, android-4.2-jelly-bean

i'm trying to take picture and save it to a file by using startActivityForResult(). But after tapping "Save" button it did not save anything and again opening the camera. 
Using device Samsung Galaxy S3(4.1.1) and Samsung Galaxy Nexus(4.1.1) but its woking fine with Motorola Defy(2.3.4).
Is it the issues with Android OS 4.1.1 or Device ?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    File file = null;
    Date date = new Date();
    try {
        file = new File("photosearch-"+date.getTime()+".jpeg");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        Log.e(TAG, " startActivityForResult");
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_ACTIVITY);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+e);
        //Check if sdcard is accessible
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to access SD Card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getActivity().finish();
    }

}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult....");

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AnotherListActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().finish();
    }
    if(resultCode == CAMERA_ACTIVITY){
        Log.d(TAG, "It should come here..");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have problem in you Extra Parameter, use this example [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

Comment: Thanks. Do u mean:                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));